# Python: message_filter AttributeError when registering callback

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic, image, message-filter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've wrapped my python node in a class, and I've been trying to approximate sync two messages at once (one being `Image` and another custom message `ofMsg` that consists of two `Float32`s) as below:

```
Class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/usb_cam/image_raw", Image)
        self.opticalflow_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/opticalflow", ofMsg)
        self.ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([self.image_sub, self.opticalflow_sub], 10, 0.1, allow_headerless=True)
        self.ts.registerCallback(self.callback)

    def callback(self, image, custom_message):
        #...

    def main(self):
        rospy.init_node('node')
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            rospy.spin()
            self.rate.sleep()
```

However, I get:
`AttributeError: 'Subscriber' object has no attribute 'registerCallback'`

I've been looking at other questions regarding `message_filters` in python with approximate time synchronizes, and they seem to have implemented things similarly (albeit outside of a class) and I can't really see where I might have gone wrong. My `package.xml` seems to check out as well, `catkin_make` works just fine.

Any suggestions?

(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on kinetic using python2.7)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306073/python:-message_filter-attributeerror-when-registering-callback/) by [almond](https://answers.ros.org/users/38074/almond/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change your subscription to following and it should work.

```
self.image_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/usb_cam/image_raw", Image)
self.opticalflow_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/opticalflow", ofMsg)
```

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2018-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

message filters has its own subscriber method so you should change it so that you are calling
message_filters.Subscriber instead of rospy.Subscriber. I made this same mistake.

---

Originally posted by [bmgatten](https://answers.ros.org/users/41434/bmgatten/) with karma: 11 on 2019-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1